# Ciclo for, número de alumnos por categoría - Python

Tags: python-3.x

Me han mandado un ejercicio donde tengo que hallar diversas cosas, pero solo en uno estoy teniendo problema, el cual es de obtener el número de alumnos por categoría (A,B,C o D) y cada categoría tiene un rango de notas. El A de 17 a 20, el B de 14 a 17, el C de 11 a 14 y el D de 0 a 11. ¿Cómo podría plantearlo en el siguiente código? Me ayudarían mucho enserio y gracias :D

```
# z = acumulador

n = int(input("Ingresa la cantidad de alumnos: "))
z = 0
for i in range(1,n+1):
    p = float(input("Ingresa el promedio del alumno {}: ".format(i)))
        i = i+1
        z = z+p

promedio = round((z/n), 1)
print("Números de alumnos ingresados: "+str(n))
print("Número de alumnos por categoría: ")
print("Promedio total: {}".format(promedio))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quizás esto te sirva:

```
n = int(input("Ingresa la cantidad de alumnos: "))
z = 0
alumnos_por_categoria=[0,0,0,0]

for i in range(1,n+1):
    p = float(input("Ingresa el promedio del alumno {}: ".format(i)))
    i = i+1
    z = z+p
    if 0<=p<11:
        alumnos_por_categoria[3]+=1
    elif 11<=p<14:
        alumnos_por_categoria[2]+=1
    elif 14<=p<17:
        alumnos_por_categoria[1]+=1
    elif 17<=p<=20:
        alumnos_por_categoria[0]+=1


promedio = round((z/n), 1) if n>0 else 0
print("Números de alumnos ingresados: "+str(n))
print("Número de alumnos por categoría: ")
print("Categoría A: {} \nCategoría B: {} \nCategoría C: {} \nCategoría D: {}".format(alumnos_por_categoria[0],alumnos_por_categoria[1],alumnos_por_categoria[2],alumnos_por_categoria[3]))
print("Promedio total: {}".format(promedio))
```

Revisa si están bien definidos los límites de los intervalos en las condicionales.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me salvaste. No sabia como hacer esa parte de cat[0,0,0,0]. Eso que vendría a ser o tiene algún un nombre en específico?

Comment: Igual puedes utilizar cuatro variables como contadores referentes a cada una de las categorías.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda :D. Una pregunta más, como harías para poder hallar cual de  todas las notas es la mayor? He intentado usando otro if y comparando las categorias

Comment: Fuera del for: `promedio_maximo= -1`. Luego, dentro del for: `if promedio_maximo<p: promedio_maximo=p`. En promedio_maximo quedará la mayor nota.

Comment: Gracias, me ayudaste un montón :DD